# Files downloaded from django don't have file's extension

Tags: django

I'm writing a view on my `Django 1.5` progect that make the user download a file.

This is the code:

```
import mimetypes
from django.http import HttpResponse

def filedownload(request, file_name):
    down_file = File.objects.get(name = file_name)
    file_path = MEDIA_ROOT+str(down_file.file) #down_file.file is something like folder/name_file.extension
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
    response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
    return response
```

It work just fine but the file is downloaded without the extension. Why? How can I solve this? I know that I can let the webserver do this but it's a dummy project and has to works only in Django.

EDIT:
I solved thanks the answer of sk1p and using a more elaborate code found [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1710/)

Comment: Does `file_name` contain the extension?

Comment: Make sure that `X-Sendfile` header isn't doing something odd. From what I can tell, it's telling the webserver (hopefully not Django's `runserver`) to send the contents of the file you're specifying. Maybe the webserver is adding its own `Content-Disposition` header, or altering or dropping yours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying the filename to be displayed in the browser with this line:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
```

so if `file_name` doesn't contain the extension, the download won't either. So: make sure the `Content-Disposition` header contains the right filename and extension!

Comment: Also might want to quote the filename, in case it has spaces or other characters (semicolons?) that HTTP headers could misinterpret.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to replace special chars like colon or semi-colon in filename; i.e:

```
    output_zip_file = f"example;name:123.zip".replace(":", "-").replace(";", "-")
    response = HttpResponse(b'contents', content_type="application/zip")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={output_zip_file}"
    return response
```